# Android Studio Win 8.1 apk delete access denied

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I have set up APK signing in Android Studio by following the "Sign Your Release Build " method here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#sign-auto

From within Android Studio I ran:

> build > Generate Signed APK

The first time through it worked and in

> app/build/outputs

there was my signed .apk, however on subsequent generations it has failed.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageArmRelease'.
>   Failed to create 'C:\Users...\app\build\outputs\apk\app-arm-release-unaligned.apks': Access is denied

When I have investigated this file/directory seems protected and I cannot delete the file. I am running as 'Admin' and have tried both via right clicking and delete and through the CMD prompt:

```
del app-arm-release-unaligned.apks
```

During my googling I found the same problem here, but with no solution:

http://amiduos.com/support/topic/cant-delete-apk-files-from-host-when-duos-installed

I am confused as to why occurring and how to move on to generate subsequent signed APK's.

Comment: maybe you can try moving your project to a different drive which is not protected.
or like all your drives are protected and needs administrator permissions?

Comment: @AshishRanjan - none of my drives are protected and I am the administrator ...

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this out. I re-cloned my repo and when I generated the APK I could delete it again. I think that the problem was once Android Studio "failed" it somehow locked or protected the file.